# Find the angle that lets you make a bendy pipe

Tags: inverse, kinematics

I have a pipe with $n$ segments of equal length. I move the farthest end nearer than the combined length to make the pipe bend. How do I find the angle between each segment with only the combined length (straight length), the distance between each end, and the number of segments?

1. $\theta$ is the angle to solve for
2. $l$ is segment length
3. $n$ is the number of segments
4. $dx$ is how the distance between ends

With only two segments I would use the law of cosines:$dx^2=2*l^2 - 2*l^2*cos \theta $

Comment: There is no longer just one angle. There are many angles.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assume all the angles between the segments are the same or the problem is underdetermined.  In that case all the bends lie on the arc of a circle.  A figure with four segments is below.  $BG$ is your $dx$, $n=4$, and $l \approx 3.6$ as drawn.  All the triangles are isosceles.  If angle $DAB=\theta, GAB=4\theta, GB=2r\sin(2\theta),l=BD=2r\sin(\theta/2)$.  You need to use $l, GB$ to get $r, \theta$

[image]